# Count Pattern Matching in R

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

How would one efficiently count the number of instances of one character string which occur within another character string?

Below is my code to date. It successfully identifies if any instance of the one string occurs in the other string. However, I do not know how to extend it from a TRUE/FALSE relationship to a counting relationship.

```
x <- ("Hello my name is Christopher. Some people call me Chris")
y <- ("Chris is an interesting person to be around")
z <- ("Because he plays sports and likes statistics")

lll <- tolower(list(x,y,z))
dict <- tolower(c("Chris", "Hell"))

mmm <- matrix(nrow=length(lll), ncol=length(dict), NA)

for (i in 1:length(lll)) {
for (j in 1:length(dict)) {
    mmm[i,j] <- sum(grepl(dict[j],lll[i]))
}
}
mmm
```

It yields:

```
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    0
 [3,]    0    0
```

Since the lower-case string "chris" appears twice in the `lll[1]` I would like `mmm[1,1]` to be 2 instead of 1.

Real example is much higher dimension...so would love if code could be vectorized instead of using my brute force for loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two quick tips:

1. avoid the dual for-loop, you dont need it ;)
2. use the `stringr` package

---

```
library(stringr)

dict <- setNames(nm=dict)  # simply for neatness
lapply(dict, str_count, string=lll)
# $chris
# [1] 2 1 0
#
# $hell
# [1] 1 0 0
```

#### Or as a matrix:

```
#  sapply(dict, str_count, string=lll)
#      chris hell
# [1,]     2    1
# [2,]     1    0
# [3,]     0    0
```

Comment: Thx @Ricardo. I received many other great answers. As mentioned below...would love if other SO users could weigh in on most efficient way to solve the problem (given suggestions below).

Comment: that will vary by your definition of "efficient".  Have a look at the `microbenchmark` package.  Note that `stringr` is syntax sugar to make it easier to work with strings.  Coding it yourself will always be as fast or faster.

Comment: That being said `efficiency = n_uses * code_run_time + programmer_time`.  A computer's time is relatively cheap.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this:

```
count.matches <- function(pat, vec) sapply(regmatches(vec, gregexpr(pat, vec)), length)
mapply(count.matches, c('chris', 'hell'), list(lll))
#      chris hell
# [1,]     2    1
# [2,]     1    0
# [3,]     0    0
```

Comment: I like this as a solution too as it does not rely on installing `stringr` library. But code in `stringr` is just so simple. Thanks so much for suggested solution (I wish I could accept both)!! Will leave it to SO community to let me know what one is better.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `sum(grepl(dict[j],lll[i]))`, try `sum(gregexpr(dict[j],lll[i])[[1]] > 0)`

Comment: Works great now too. Thx. Looks like there are multiple ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1):

```
llll<-rep(lll,length(dict))
dict1<-rep(dict,each=length(lll))


 do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y)list(y,sum(gregexpr(y,x)[[1]] > 0)), llll,dict1))
                                                        [,1]    [,2]
hello my name is christopher. some people call me chris "chris" 2   
chris is an interesting person to be around             "chris" 1   
because he plays sports and likes statistics            "chris" 0   
hello my name is christopher. some people call me chris "hell"  1   
chris is an interesting person to be around             "hell"  0   
because he plays sports and likes statistics            "hell"  0
```

You can then use `reshape` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the qdap package.  The CRAN version should work fine but you may want the [dev version](https://github.com/trinker/qdap)

```
library(qdap)

termco(c(x, y, z), 1:3, c('chris', 'hell'))

##   3 word.count     chris      hell
## 1 1         10 2(20.00%) 1(10.00%)
## 2 2          8 1(12.50%)         0
## 3 3          7         0         0


termco(c(x, y, z), 1:3, c('chris', 'hell'))$raw

##   3 word.count chris hell
## 1 1         10     2    1
## 2 2          8     1    0
## 3 3          7     0    0
```