# Calculate the number of occurrence of a given character in each row of a data frame?

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I would like to computer the number of these following characters :

```
"AAA", "BBB", "CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF"
```

In a data frame like this

```
 Id   Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4
  1   xtAAA  bBBB   fCCC   ::hFF
  2   xtAAA         ZEEE   ::FFF
  3   ooCCC  bBBB   CkCC   
  4          BBBh   fCCC   :-LLL
  5   xtAAA  lBBB   eCCC   ::FFF
  6                 BBBC   
  7   xtAAA  CvCC   fCCC   BBBlF
```

Then obtain a new data frame with :

```
 Id   Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   number.of.AAA   number.of.BBB  number.of.CCC
  1   xtAAA  bBBB   fCCC   ::hFF
  2   xtAAA         ZEEE   ::FFF
  3   ooCCC  bBBB   CkCC   
  4          BBBh   fCCC   :-LLL
  5   xtAAA  lBBB   eCCC   ::FFF
  6                 BBBC   
  7   xtAAA  CvCC   fCCC   BBBlF
```

I have seen many scripts but none of them does what I am aiming to do.

Comment: Please add the code for us to recreate the data frame.Also add what is the expected output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19667053/244811

Comment: Try `cbind(df1, t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) sapply(v1, function(y) length(grep(y, x)))))` where `v1` is the vector of values

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

```
# smaller subset of the data
temp <- data.frame(matrix(c("xtAAA", "bBBB", "fCCC", "::hFF", "xtAAA","ZEEE", "::FFF"), byrow = T), stringsAsFactors=F)

# build a little counter function
counter <- function(strings, input) {
  return(sapply(strings, function(i) sum(grepl(i, input))))
}

# get the counts
myCounts <- t(sapply(1:nrow(temp), function(i) counter(strings=c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), temp[i,])))
```

You can add this to your data.frame using `cbind`:

```
allDone <- cbind(temp, myCounts)
```