# Finding Abbreviations in Data with R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr, tidytext

In my data (which is text), there are abbreviations.

Is there any functions or code that search for abbreviations in text? For example, detecting 3-4-5 capital letter abbreviations and letting me count how often they happen.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to count one abbreviation at a time or you would have list of abbreviations. Is it possible to explain the requirement in more detail using an example. Thanks

Comment: Regex based functions will be your friend here. Also have a look at [str_count()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html)

Comment: You could do: `strings <- c("ABC text ABCD text ABCDef text again ABCDE ABCDG");

library(stringr);
str_count(strings, pattern = "\\b[A-Z]{3}\\b");` To get the 4, 5, etc. you can change the `{3}` to `{4}`, etc.

Comment: I think Mike's suggestion might be the best fit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> detecting 3-4-5 capital letter abbreviations

You may use

```
\b[A-Z]{3,5}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQC9F7/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Z]{3,5}` - 3, 4  or 5 capital letters (use `[[:upper:]]` to match letters other than ASCII, too)
- `\b` - a word boundary.

[R demo online](http://ideone.com/rp9i5p) (leveraging the regex occurrence count code from [@TheComeOnMan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667054/3832970))

```
abbrev_regex <- "\\b[A-Z]{3,5}\\b";
x <- "XYZ was seen at WXYZ with VWXYZ and did ABCDEFGH."
sum(gregexpr(abbrev_regex,x)[[1]] > 0)
## => [1] 3
regmatches(x, gregexpr(abbrev_regex, x))[[1]]
## => [1] "XYZ"   "WXYZ"  "VWXYZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `[A-Z]` to match any ocurrence of acapital letter. If you want this pattern to be repeated 3 times you can add `\1{3}` to your regex. Consider using variables and a loop to get the job done for 3 to 5 repetition times.