# Is there a faster way to calculate number of keyword matches for each observation in a dataset

Tags: r, string-matching

My dataset contains variables: An integer code (INS) and a text description (Beskr).

I have performed a webscraping in which I extracted different keywords for each of the 88 different codes. I want to count the number of matches in the text descriptions with these keywords and store the count in a new variable for each code.

With using only a few observations it runs fast with the nested for-loops but when I increase the size of the data it takes a really long time. is there any easier and faster way to do this? The dataset should contain columns for code, descriptions and 88 variables with counts of keyword matches.

```
#For testing
descriptions <- c("Ska pyssla med bade Fiske och vattenbruk", "fiske", "jordbruk", 
            "tillverkning", "vattenbruk", "motorfordon")
ins <- 1:6

testDFScrape <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow =6))
testDFScrape[,1] <- ins
testDFScrape[,2] <- descriptions
colnames(testDFScrape) <- c("INS", "Beskr")

#Add the variable columns for the matches
colAdditions <- paste(rep("NbrOfMatchesWithCode", 3), 1:3, sep = "" )
testDFScrape[colAdditions] <- NA

#Faked keywords, the real data contains 88 groups of keywords.
scrapedTextTokens<- list(keywordscode1 = c("fiske", "jordbruk"), 
                         keywordscode2 = ("tillverkning"), 
                         keywordscode3 = c("motorfordon", "vattenbruk"))

#For each row, Count matches for each of the 88 Groups different keywords

keyMatchCount <- 0
for(rowNbr in 1:nrow(testDFScrape)){  
  for(i in 1:length(scrapedTextTokens)){
    for(keyword in scrapedTextTokens[[i]]){
      if(str_detect(tolower(testDFScrape[rowNbr, 2]), keyword)){
             keyMatchCount <- keyMatchCount + 1} 
    } 
    testDFScrape[rowNbr, i + 2] <- keyMatchCount
    keyMatchCount <- 0
  }
}
```

EDIT: Solution with the help of eastclintw00d

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in 1:length(scrapedTextTokens)){
  df <- as.data.frame(lapply(scrapedTextTokens[[i]], str_count, string = testDFScrape$Beskr))
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(total = rowSums(.))
  testDFScrape[ ,i + 2] <- df$total
}
```

Comment: I think this post might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666965/count-pattern-matching-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666965/count-pattern-matching-in-r) to your problem. It gives you counts per keyword. You only have to sum up the keyword groups.

```
library(stringr)

lll <- tolower(c("Ska pyssla med bade Fiske och vattenbruk", "fiske", "jordbruk", 
                    "tillverkning", "vattenbruk", "motorfordon"))
dict <- list("fiske", "jordbruk", "tillverkning", "motorfordon", "vattenbruk")

as.data.frame(lapply(dict, str_count, string=lll), col.names = dict)
```

Comment: Hi,  A lot faster on 8000 observations with your solution and the code I wrote. Thank you. I am sure there might be more improvement but this is suffice for me. Still have one for-loop in there.